# Python Greedy Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I am currently working on this code and the only thing that seems to work is the "no solution." Also it seems that the code has an infinite loop and I can't seem to figure out how to solve it. If someone could point out my mistake it would be appreciated.

```
def greedySum(L, s):

""" input: s, positive integer, what the sum should add up to
               L, list of unique positive integers sorted in descending order
        Use the greedy approach where you find the largest multiplier for 
        the largest value in L then for the second largest, and so on to 
        solve the equation s = L[0]*m_0 + L[1]*m_1 + ... + L[n-1]*m_(n-1)
        return: the sum of the multipliers or "no solution" if greedy approach does 
                not yield a set of multipliers such that the equation sums to 's'
    """

        if len(L) == 0:
            return "no solution"            
            sum_total = (0, ())
        elif L[0] > k:
            sum_total = greed(L[1:], k)
        else:
            no_number = L[0]
            value_included, take = greed(L, k - L[0])
            value_included += 1
            no_value, no_take = greed(L[1:], k)
            if k >= 0:
                sum_total = (value_included, take + (no_number,))
            else:
                sum_total = (value_included, take + (no_number,))
        return sum_total
    sum_multiplier = greed(L, s)
    return "no solution" if sum(sum_multiplier[1]) != s else sum_multiplier[0]
```

Second method:

```
    def greedySum(L, s):
      answer = []
    try:
      while (s >= L[0]):
        total = s// L[0]
        s -= (total * L[0])
        answer.append(total)
        L = L[1:]
     return(str(answer)[1:-1])
   except:
     return("no solution")
```

Comment: Your code is messed up by a quote mark. Could you fix that please?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I just noticed. Is there anything else I need to fix such as making the code more simple?

Comment: return isn't a function I don't think. Don't put parentheses after it.

Comment: What does `greed` do? Could you include the code for that?

Comment: @ElliotRoberts it's not, you're right; it's a statement. OP: *"Is there anything else I need to fix"* - does it work? Have you tested it? Why do you think the code needs to be simpler? If it's **working code** and you think there's room for improvement, see [codereview.se].

Comment: I tested it, it keeps saying it has an infinite loop. So I was wondering if there is an alternate method to fix the infinite loop

Comment: @ElliotRoberts oops forgot about that. I though that the cause of the error was based on another def so I removed it. That was greed. I think I will post an alternate version that has a similar problem as well.

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do, but the line sum_total = (0, ()) after the return "no solution" never executes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works:

```
def greedySum(L, s):
    multiplier_sum = 0
    for l in L:
        (quot,rem) = divmod(s,l) # see how many 'l's you can fit in 's'
        multiplier_sum += quot   # add that number to the multiplier_sum
        s = rem                  # update the remaining amount

    # If at the end and s is 0, return the multiplier_sum
    # Otherwise, signal that there is no solution
    return multiplier_sum if s == 0 else "no solution"
```

I would offer more help on what is wrong with your code, but that is for the moment a moving target - you keep changing it!

```
>>> greedySum([4,2],8)
2
>>> greedySum([4,2],9)
'no solution'
>>> greedySum([4,2,1],9)
3
```

Comment: @June_Joshua Happy to help. Feel free to up vote and accept if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I also have a few questions involving graph theory, if that is okay with you.

Comment: @June_Joshua Probably better to put that in a separate question. :)

Comment: thank you for telling me. I already figured it out. Thank you for the help. :) @Alec